# Event 4634 is logged every 5 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a hosted server that I use for web hosting, Server 2016. I access the box via RDP
Every 5 minutes it logs me out, and then logs me back in again. 
The screen goes black for 15 seconds during this process (grrr)

In the Windows Logs > Security Event log I see event 4634 (Logoff) followed by 4776 (Credential Validation), 4672 (Special Login) and 4624 (Login)

The every 5 minutes thing must mean something...

I'm a web dev, but I understand networking pretty well. I've tried the gpedit settings for Remote Desktop Services/Session Time Limits, they don't help.

Comment: Are you under the impression that we instinctively know what those Event ID's are? Maybe post the actual details of those events in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Oddest thing ever. I kept looking and found events being logged in the 'admin' area of the Event log too, at the same time. The events had to do with an IP address that I had configured and then stopped using.

I went into the Network Connections area and disabled the second nic and the Virtual switch that was created by the HyperV install (that is currently turned off) and the problem stopped happening.